# Try catch in PHP mysql_connect

Tags: php

I written two mysql connection. I want to continue execution if one of the connection got error. So I used try catch. But while connection failed it stops execution. How can I continue execution  with other connection?

Comment: What error do you get? Paste your code.

Comment: If it's creating a PHP Fatal error then you won't be able to catch this in a try catch block.

Comment: The mysql extension is pretty outdated and it doesn't support OOP stuff.

Comment: Error means connection failed error. I want to continue execution using another connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, don't use mysql_connect, use PDO, that also happens to support Exception throwing on errors :)

As a generic answer, have a separate try...catch for each connection attempt, if one of the connection fails then throw an exception on that but you can still continue with the other. You may need to nest the connection try...catches with a third try...catch if there's something outside these two you want to catch.

pseudo code:

```
try {
    try {
        attemptConnectionOne();
    } catch () { /* Connection failed */ }

    try {
        attemptConnectionTwo();
    } catch () { /* Connection failed */ }

} catch () { /* whatever else you may need */ }
```